# Trying to concatenate strings in a function with parameter self in python

Tags: python, function, concatenation

I am working on an application to save and analyze my cryptocurrency data. I use 2 different apps, hotbit and binance. Since I have bought, for example, BTC on both hotbit and binance, I want to add HB to the end of BTC to specify that it needs to go into the hotbit table I've created. It should look like 'BTCHB'.

```
def which_application(self):

    print("Which application was this transaction made on? Type either 'hotbit' or 'binance'")
    which_application_prompt = input("").strip().lower()

    if which_application_prompt == 'hotbit':
        self = self + 'HB'
        return(self)

    elif which_application_prompt == 'binance':
        pass

    else:
        print("Invalid input.")
        which_application(self)
```

I've created this function and everything works smoothly inside the function. However, when I call the function and add a value in place of self, it doesn't add HB to it. Any ideas?

Comment: is this function inside a class?

Comment: No, it is not. I can add the code I want to add HB to in the post if it helps.

Comment: self is not a reserved word in python, so you can use it in this context, but by convention we used it also to refeer to a instance of a class. If this don't make sense to you yet, just know that it's better to use a name other than self for that parameter. How are you calling the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing reassigning the value to `self` in your recursive call, a fixed version could be:

```
def which_application(self):
    print("Which application was this transaction made on? Type either 'hotbit' or 'binance'")
    which_application_prompt = input("").strip().lower()
    if which_application_prompt == 'hotbit':
        self = self + 'HB'
        return(self)
    elif which_application_prompt == 'binance':
        return self
    else:
        print("Invalid input.")
        self = which_application(self)
        return self
```

Works:

```
$ python3 demo.py
Which application was this transaction made on? Type either 'hotbit' or 'binance'
hotbit
testHB
```

If you call `which_application` again in the else statement a possibly returned value is lost as you do not assign it to self.

Another flaw is when you type `binance` nothing is returned - None to be exact.

```
$ python3 demo.py
Which application was this transaction made on? Type either 'hotbit' or 'binance'
binance
None
```

Last, a while loop is better than a recursion. Loop until a return.

Comment: if you enter a wrong input in the first time, and a correct one in the second time, it still returns None, why is this happening?

Comment: The else did not have a return statement, returning None. I will fix it above.

Answer (score 0):

When you recurse (call the function from within itself), you're also "recreating" its locals, so `self` is no longer referring to the same object as `self` in the parent call.

Use a loop instead of recursion (and consider using a less confusing parameter name than `self`):

```
def which_application(transaction):
    while True:
        print("Which application was this transaction made on? Type either 'hotbit' or 'binance'")
        which_application_prompt = input("").strip().lower()

        if which_application_prompt == 'hotbit':
            transaction = transaction + 'HB'
            return(transaction)

        elif which_application_prompt == 'binance':
            break

        else:
            print("Invalid input.")
            # since we're neither `break`'ing nor `return`'ing from here, 
            # the loop will start over
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that didn't fix it. The main problem is with this part I believe. 
if which_application_prompt == 'hotbit':
            self = self + 'HB'
            return(self)

Say I added print(self) at the end of this if statement, it will work as intended. The result will be 'BTCHB'. But when I want to return 'BTCHB' to another function, it comes back as 'BTC'

Comment: @TaimurAdam Odd. If you define this function as listed in my answer, `which_application("trans1")` returns `"trans1HB"` as expected when I input "hotbit"